# SQL Server foreign key data issue

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables

- crm.Documents
- crm.GroupDocuments
- schedular.Groups

`Documents` table looks like

```
Id   Name
-----------
1    Test
```

`GroupDocuments` table looks like

```
Id | GroupId | DocumentId
---+---------+------------
1  |  1      | 1
2  |  2      | 1
```

`Group` table looks like

```
Id | Name
---+--------
1  | Sales
2  | Service
3  | Techs
```

The code to create these tables is :

```
CREATE TABLE [crm].[Documents]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [FileType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Bytes] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [IsShared] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [UploadDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [LastSaveDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Documents] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [scheduler].[Groups]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Groups] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [crm].[GroupDocuments]
(
    [GroupId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DocumentId] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_GroupDocuments] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([GroupId] ASC, [DocumentId] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [crm].[GroupDocuments] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_GroupDocuments_Documents_GroupId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([GroupId]) REFERENCES [crm].[Documents] ([Id])
                ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [crm].[GroupDocuments] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_GroupDocuments_Documents_GroupId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [crm].[GroupDocuments]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_GroupDocuments_Groups_DocumentId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([DocumentId]) REFERENCES [scheduler].[Groups] ([Id])
                ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [crm].[GroupDocuments] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_GroupDocuments_Groups_DocumentId]
GO
```

When I run

```
INSERT INTO crm.GroupDocuments (GroupId, DocumentId) 
VALUES (3, 1)
```

I get this error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_GroupDocuments_Documents_GroupId".
> The conflict occurred in database "Scheduler", table "crm.Documents",
> column 'Id'.

There is an Id 3 on the group table and an Id 1 on the documents table. Can someone please explain why this error would occur?

Comment: Should your `GroupDocuments.GroupId` really reference `Documents.Id` and `GroupDocuments.DocumentId` references `Group.Id` - isn't that just wrong ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've **criss-crossed** the referenced columns in the definition of your foreign key constraints .... your `DocumentID` references `Groups.Id`, while `GroupId` references `Documents.Id`....

Change your FK statements to:

```
-- "GroupId" should reference "Groups.Id" (not "Documents.Id") .....
ALTER TABLE [crm].[GroupDocuments] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_GroupDocuments_GroupId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([GroupId]) REFERENCES [scheduler].[Groups]([Id])
                ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

-- and "DocumentId" should reference "Documents.Id" (not "Groups.Id")        
ALTER TABLE [crm].[GroupDocuments]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_GroupDocuments_DocumentId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([DocumentId]) REFERENCES [crm].[Documents]([Id])
                ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

You have inverted your FOREIGN KEY references....

```
ALTER TABLE [crm].[GroupDocuments]  
ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_GroupDocuments_Documents_GroupId] 
     FOREIGN KEY([**GroupId**]) REFERENCES [crm].[**Documents**] ([Id])
```

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand this, can you please explain?